# Populating Bootstrap table with JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, bootstrap-5

So, I am building an ASP.NET web site, and I have a customer search page that uses the following form code:

```
  <form class="was-validated" id="frmSearch" name="frmSearch" method="post">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-1 text-end">Find companies where...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 text-start">
                    <select ID="SearchField" name="SearchField" Class="form-control rounded" required>
                        <option value="" selected>Search by...</option>
                        <option value="company_name">Company Name</option>
                        <option value="city">City</option>
                        <option value="federal_ein">EIN</option>
                        <option value="state">State</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 text-center">contains...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex">
                    <input type="text" ID="SearchValue" name="SearchValue" class="form-control rounded text-black" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 mx-auto">
                    <input type="submit" ID="btnSearch" class="btn-success btn text-white" text="search" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I am using jQuery to process the form submission to call a web handler for performing the search:

```
 $(function () {
            $('#frmSearch').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var json = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(event.target)));
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'customersearch.ashx',
                    data: json,
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.Payload);
                        if (data.Status == 'OK') {
                            $('#customers').bootstrapTable({
                                data: data.Payload
                            });
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The webhandler code is pretty simple:

```
        public void ProcessRequest ( HttpContext ctx ) {
            DataResponse reply = new DataResponse ();
            ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            var jsonData = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            SearchRequest req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchRequest> ( jsonData );
            if (jsonData == null || req == null) {
                reply.Status = "INVALID_REQUEST";
                var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reply);
                ctx.Response.Write ( response );
                return;
            }
            else {
                reply.Status = "OK";
                var records = CustomerDB.GetAll($"{req.SearchField} like '%{req.SearchValue}%'");
                reply.Payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject ( records, Formatting.Indented );
                var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reply);
                ctx.Response.Write ( response );

            }
        }
```

A class called DataResponse is used to contain the response from the web server:

```
    public class DataResponse {
        public string Status { get; set; } = "OK";
        public string Payload { get; set; } = null;

        public DataResponse ( ) { }
    }
```

The Payload is used to hold the serialized JSON data from the database, while Status holds the results of the request.

Finally, there is a bootstrap table in the page where the results of the search should be displayed, using this code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                <table data-toggle="table" class="display table table-bordered" id="customers">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="company_name">Company</th>
                            <th data-field="federal_ein">EIN</th>
                            <th data-field="City">City</th>
                            <th data-field="state">State</th>
                            <th data-field="creation_date">Added</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now, all of this code works perfectly, EXCEPT when the web handler returns its data, the table doesn't populate, despite the fact the data is there, as shown by the screenshot below demonstrating what's coming back in the response.

[Screenshot showing JSON data coming back from web handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q3vU.png)

My issue is trying to figure out why the JSON data doesn't populate into the bootstrap table.  Thanks in advance for your help, everyone.

Comment: So `.Payload` is a string? Why? You can just `return Ok(records);` and let MVC do the work to serialise json.

Comment: Payload is serialized JSON of a <List> of records returned from the database.

Comment: `reply.Payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject` it's a string containing json right? `data: data.Payload` but you're assuming it is a deserialised object / array?

Comment: The screenshot included with the question shows the payload's data in an alert window.

Comment: Exactly, it's not `[object Object]`. Have you examined the variable in the javascript debugger? I bet that `typeof reply.Payload === 'string'`.

Comment: If that's true then what do I do to address this?  The data is coming back as JSON.

Comment: Yes, that's what I get, a string when I do typeof.  I don't understand, since the webhandler uses JsonConvert.SerializeObject to change the <List> to JSON, and the contenttype of the return is set to "application/json".  Any clues here?

Comment: You're serializing the list to a json string, then serializing that again as the result. So either parse it again in javascript, or change `DataResponse` to a generic type with a `T Payload`. Or google some other way to wrap your responses.